# Swift: Sometimes Generic.Type fails if I don't use MyClass.self

Tags: swift, generics

Why does this code fail with the error message `Expected member name or constructor call after type name` while the next one works?

Block 1 (failing):

```
public static func newHMAC<A: KCCrypto_HashAlgo>(hashAlgo: A.Type, key: Array<UInt8>) -> KCCrypto_HMAC<A> {
    return KCCrypto_HMAC<A>()
}
_ = KCCrypto.newHMAC(KCCrypto_SHA2_256, key: Array<UInt8>())
```

Block 2 (working):

```
public static func newHash<A: KCCrypto_HashAlgo>(algo: A.Type) -> A {
    return A()
}
_ = KCCrypto.newHash(KCCrypto_SHA2_256)
```

---

The first block works if I use `KCCrypto_SHA2_256.self`:

```
_ = KCCrypto.newHMAC(KCCrypto_SHA2_256.self, key: Array<UInt8>())
```

The second one also works with `KCCrypto_SHA2_256.self`, but I don't understand why I have to use `.self` in the first block.

---

**Edit:** The `KCCrypto_HMAC`-class looks like this:

```
public class KCCrypto_HMAC<A: KCCrypto_HashAlgo> {
    public required init() {
        print("HMAC is not implemented yet.")
    }
}
```